# From a list of dicts, return the list of dicts but only with specific key/value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I would originally have a list of dicts like so:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere rep",
    "body": "quia et suscipit"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vita"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi"
  }
]
```

If i had a list for example like `['id', 'body']`, I would want my new list of dicts to be:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "body": "quia et suscipit"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "body": "est rerum tempore vita"
  },
  {
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict_list = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere rep",
    "body": "quia et suscipit"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vita"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi"
  }
]

keys = ['id', 'body']

result = [{k: d[k] for k in keys if k in d} for d in dict_list]

print(result)
>>> [{'body': 'quia et suscipit', 'id': 1},
     {'body': 'est rerum tempore vita', 'id': 2},
     {'id': 3}]
```

The line that does the trick is `result = [{k: d[k] for k in keys if k in d} for d in dict_list]`. This is a list comprehension that creates a `dict` for every `dict` in `dict_list`, keeping only the keys in the `keys` list.

Comment: In general, try to describe what it is you are doing and then provide the solution. Code dumps aren't the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just rebuild the dicts in the list using dict comprehension and filtering of keys:

```
result = [{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in ["id","body"]} for d in dlist]

print(result)
```

outputs:

```
[{'body': 'quia et suscipit', 'id': 1}, {'body': 'est rerum tempore vita', 'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_dicts = [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere rep",
    "body": "quia et suscipit"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vita"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi"
  }
]
item = "body"  # Item to be searched for
for i in list_of_dicts:
    print(i)
    if item in i:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

you can replace print with any action, and add/change to 'item'

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension to rebuild the dict:

```
new_dict= [{"id":i["id"], "body":i["body"]} for i in d]
```